# KTOR API httpsredirect plugin does not redirect correct headers when behind reverse proxy (Apache)

Tags: kotlin, redirect, https, ktor

I have a KTOR API ((https://github.com/Digital-Architects-Avans/rmc-api) which uses the authentication plugin to authenticate users accessing certain endpoints with an JWT token.

I'm also using the httpredirect plugin to redirect users accessing an endpoint using the http protocol to the https counterpart.

**The problem:**
The httpredirect plugin redirects the call from the POST `http://localhost:8080/user/signup` endpoint to the HTTPS counterpart GET endpoint, the authentication plugin then kicks in and fails to authenticate the user because the original POST request does not have a Authorization Bearer token header. I then get a 401 unauthorized.

There is no GET /user/signup endpoint, it somehow fails to correctly redirect the POST method to the HTTPS counterpart. Is it because I am running this on a localhost with a self-signed certificate? Do I have to configure the ForwardHeaders plugin because I am behind a reverse-proxy? Am I?

The POST request:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/user/signup
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "email": "staff@email.com",
  "userType": "STAFF",
  "password": "StrongPassword1!"
}
```

Httpsredirect plugin

```
install(HttpsRedirect) {
        // install(XForwardedHeaderSupport) // Required when behind a reverse-proxy
        sslPort = 8443
        permanentRedirect = true
    }
```

The endpoint route:

```
fun Route.userRoutes() {

    route("/user") {
        rateLimit {
            post("/signup") {
                val signUpDTO = call.receive<SignupDTO>()

                try {
                    val newUser = userRepository.createUser(signUpDTO)
                    val token = tokenManager.generateJWTToken(newUser)

                    call.response.header("Authorization", token)
                    call.respondText(Json.encodeToString(newUser), status = HttpStatusCode.Created)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    throw EmailAlreadyRegistered()
                }
            }
```

The logs:

```
2023-11-30 22:28:24.963 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] INFO  Application - Responding at http://0.0.0.0:8080
2023-11-30 22:28:24.964 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] INFO  Application - Responding at https://0.0.0.0:8443
2023-11-30 22:28:31.231 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE i.k.s.p.c.ContentNegotiation - Skipping response body transformation from HttpStatusCode to OutgoingContent for the POST /user/signup request because the HttpStatusCode type is ignored. See [ContentNegotiationConfig::ignoreType].
2023-11-30 22:28:31.231 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE i.k.s.p.statuspages.StatusPages - No handler found for status code 301 Moved Permanently for call: /user/signup
**2023-11-30 22:28:31.234 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE Application - Status: 301 Moved Permanently, HTTP method: POST, User agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14 (Java/17.0.9)**
2023-11-30 22:28:31.237 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [user, signup]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /user, segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /user
    /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER), segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)
      /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/signup, segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/signup
**        /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/signup/(method:POST), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/signup/(method:POST)**
      /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/signin, segment:1 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/signin
      /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default"), segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")
        /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/users, segment:1 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/users
        /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [id=[signup]] @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}
          /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}/(method:GET)
          /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}/(method:PUT), segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}/(method:PUT)
          /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}/(method:DELETE), segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}/(method:DELETE)
        /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/me, segment:1 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/me
  /(authenticate "default"), segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /(authenticate "default")
    /(authenticate "default")/vehicle, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate "default")/vehicle
  /rental, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /rental
Matched routes:
  "" -> "user" -> "(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)" -> "signup" -> "(method:POST)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/signup/(method:POST)
2023-11-30 22:28:31.345 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [user, signup]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /user, segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /user
    /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER), segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)
      /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/signup, segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/signup
        /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/signup/(method:POST), segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/signup/(method:POST)
      /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/signin, segment:1 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/signin
      /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default"), segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")
        /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/users, segment:1 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/users
        /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}, segment:2 -> SUCCESS; Parameters [id=[signup]] @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}
          /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}/(method:GET), segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}/(method:GET)
          /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}/(method:PUT), segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}/(method:PUT)
          /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}/(method:DELETE), segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}/(method:DELETE)
        /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/me, segment:1 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/me
  /(authenticate "default"), segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /(authenticate "default")
    /(authenticate "default")/vehicle, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate "default")/vehicle
  /rental, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /rental
Matched routes:
**  "" -> "user" -> "(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)" -> "(authenticate "default")" -> "{id}" -> "(method:GET)"**
Route resolve result:
**  SUCCESS; Parameters [id=[signup]] @ /user/(RateLimit KTOR_NO_NAME_RATE_LIMITER)/(authenticate "default")/{id}/(method:GET)**
**2023-11-30 22:28:31.346 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] TRACE io.ktor.server.auth.Authentication - Trying to authenticate /user/signup with null**
**2023-11-30 22:28:31.348 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] TRACE io.ktor.server.auth.Authentication - Authentication failed for /user/signup with provider io.ktor.server.auth.jwt.JWTAuthenticationProvider@5345ae8
2023-11-30 22:28:31.351 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] TRACE i.k.s.p.statuspages.StatusPages - Call /user/signup failed with cause rmc.error.AuthenticationFailed: {"Exception":"Authentication Failed"}**
2023-11-30 22:28:31.358 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] TRACE i.k.s.p.statuspages.StatusPages - Executing (io.ktor.server.application.ApplicationCall, rmc.error.AuthenticationFailed) -> kotlin.Unit for exception rmc.error.AuthenticationFailed: {"Exception":"Authentication Failed"} for call /user/signup
2023-11-30 22:28:31.359 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] TRACE i.k.s.p.c.ContentNegotiation - Skipping because body is already converted.
2023-11-30 22:28:31.360 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-2] TRACE Application - Status: 401 Unauthorized, HTTP method: GET, User agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14 (Java/17.0.9)
```

I tried to configure the ForwardHeaders plugin, though the documentation on this is very poorly and this did not work.

The POST method does work correctly on https://localhost:8443/user/signup where I am getting a 200 OK and valid JSON user object returned.

Weird thing is, calls to GET endpoints using the HTTP protocol such as the `GET http://localhost:8080/user/users` do work. This is because the requests to this endpoint use different headers, and the problem lies in that the httpsredirect does not redirect with the correct headers.

```
GET http://localhost:8080/user/users
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovLzAuMC4wLjA6ODQ0My9zaWdudXAiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovLzAuMC4wLjA6ODQ0My8iLCJlbWFpbCI6Im93bmVyMUBlbWFpbC5jb20iLCJ1c2VyVHlwZSI6IkNMSUVOVCIsInVzZXJJZCI6MSwiZXhwIjoxNzAxMzg4MDU3fQ.INihJWmIc5VvyDv6Ehn42nrUGpf_4uyhJOEHjetlXx8
```

**Edit:**
It looks like I am behind a reverse proxy and the httpsredirect isnt headers arent correctly being forwarded. To try and fix this I installed the ForwardedHeaders plugin which is designed to handle headers provided by reverse proxies, but it still does not work.

```
    install(ForwardedHeaders) // WARNING: for security, do not include this if not behind a reverse proxy
    install(XForwardedHeaders) // WARNING: for security, do not include this if not behind a reverse proxy
    install(HttpsRedirect) {
        sslPort = 8443
        permanentRedirect = true
    }
```

**Edit 2:**
The httpsredirect plugin uses either a 301 or 302 status code, which possibly automaticly results in a GET request. I'm trying to figure out a way to use a 307.

Comment: If you want to respond with 307 instead of 301 or 302, just copy the source code of the `HttpsRedirect` plugin and the `ApplicationCall.respondRedirect` method to change the responding code in the `respondRedirect`.